# Markdown: How to make a text bold within xml code section

Tags: xml, markdown

I want to highlight a property (SOMEPROPERTY) within xml text block with bold, like:

```
<Publish Dialog="Dialog" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="{Next Dialog Id}">SOMEPROPERTY</Publish>
```

But ** does not work in this case.

````
```xml
<Publish Dialog="Dialog" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="{Next Dialog Id}">**SOMEPROPERTY**</Publish>
```
````

How can I make it bold?

Comment: answer on meta! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183610/how-to-combine-bold-and-code-sample-in-markdown

Comment: The answer does not provide the solution for code block.

Comment: This is not possible without some sort of add-on. A code block is only intended to be plain text, nothing more. True. some sites have syntax highlighting which adds color/bold/italics/etc, but that is done via an add-on and is not part of Markdown. Ans syntax highlighters define their styles by the syntax of the code block, not user defined styles.